# Draw large number of paths in drawRect

Tags: ios, core-graphics, cglayer

What would be the optimal way to render a large number of paths < 512 in a view's drawRect?

I would like to draw up to 512, 2 pixel wide segments in real time and am not sure on how to do this with highest performance.

Creating and drawing all of these segments as a BezierPath or multiple bezierPaths is not fast enough.

I have read that CGLayers can be used and rendered into the target UIView.

After setting up the layer from the views context and writing to the layer elsewhere with its own context the layer can be drawn into the view with

```
CGContextDrawLayerAtPoint(context, point, layer);
```

If something is constantly drawing in the layer, when should it notify the UIView with setNeedsDisplay and can they be kept in sync? e.g. without dispatching setNeedsDisplay to the main thread (this doesn't feel right).

What would be the best way to render so many paths/lines in the layer once this optimisation has been made?

Comment: Are the bezier paths static? If they are, one way is to create the paths once on init, then drawRect uses them when it needs without recreating. Title escapes me right now, but there's a wwdc 2012 video about optimizing drawing, profiling, etc.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to be really fast, use OpenGL ES ;) Otherwise, there are some general considerations:

1. Do as little duplicate work as possible. E.g. if there are 200 background polygons that remain the same between renderings, render them to a UIImage and draw that UIImage at the beginning of your -drawRect method. Avoid such things as `if(array.count < 3) { y += array.count } else { y += 3 }` because `int array_count = array.count; if(array_count < 3) { y += array_count } else { y += 3 }` is faster! Okay, in this case there is not much difference, but in many cases these kind of things do matter! Avoid creating too many objects in inner loops.
2. Use [CADisplayLink](http://ashfurrow.com/blog/animating-views-with-cadisplaylink).
3. Profile your code to see where the bottlenecks are. Are they in the drawing code, or in the code that calculates the polygons?